# SendKeys to application c#

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am having the following issue, i want to simulate a keypress from c# to a application, I tried using sendkeys, inputsimulator & interception. My question is how to deal with this? I know sendkeys is a very small class but I hope it can work out in this situation,

```
 Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("condor").FirstOrDefault();
 if (p != null)
 {
        IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(h);
        SendKeys.Send("k");
 }
```

This gives me the error:

```
SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method
```

My question is how to simulate a key press to a formless application?

Comment: "or use the SendKeys.SendWait method"

Comment: Doesn't resolve the issue, luckily I am not that stupid..

Comment: Is this a windows application or Console application? Formless?

Comment: Its a windows form application, trying to use sendkeys to another application

Comment: It seems like you are trying to access from one pc to another?

Answer (score 0):

Good day Mr Erwin!
You should try adding Thread.Sleep before getting MainWindowHandle.